# Gauge invariance prohibits the existence of other universes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, universe, observers, quantum-interpretations, gauge-invariance

I'm only a student, so most likely misunderstood. The Wikipedia article on [Relational quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_quantum_mechanics) says:

> "The universe is the sum total of everything in existence with any possibility of direct or indirect interaction with a local observer. A (physical) observer outside of the universe would require physically breaking of gauge invariance, and a concomitant alteration in the mathematical structure of gauge-invariance theory ".

Do I understand correctly that this interpretation prohibits the existence of other universes, that is, physical systems that are not directly or indirectly related to the local observer?

Comment: I wouldn't take this too seriously. Gauge invariance also prohibits photon spin, Feynman propagators and causes plenty of paradoxes in classical electromagnetism.